# is it possible with UI router to have single ui-view in index.html, and nested states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm setting up a project, and using ui-router.
requirement is to have url which keep on appending eg: #/home/contacts.
In order to achieve that, i have to use the nested states.
eg: home and home.contacts, where home state will have  in template which will get populate.

But i want to have a single ui-view at root level, index.html, which will get templates when i will hit on url, eg, home or home/contacts.
Is it possible to get this behaviour with ui-router?

in nutshell, having nested behavior[not nested, i want appending url] with single ui-view at index.html.

Note

Comment: What would a state after contacts look like?  What's the reasoning behind the requirement for appended URLs?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Could you specify the URL of the state to be explicitly home/contacts?

**See below for an example:**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {

  var routes = [
  {
    state: 'home',
    config: {
      url: '/home',
      template: '<h3>Home</h3>'
    }
  }, 
  {
    state: 'contacts',
    config: {
      url: '/home/contacts',
      template: '<h3>Contacts</h3>'
    }
  }];

  routes.forEach(function(route) {

    if (route.state) {
      $stateProvider.state(route.state, route.config);
    }
  });

});
```

**View:**

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
    <a ui-sref="contacts">Contacts</a>

    <div ui-view></div>
  </body>
```

Working Plnkr example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2).

Comment: yes, i have tried it but wanted to know the better solution with nested states.

Comment: `$stateProvider
.state('leaguesState', {
                url: '/leagues',
                template:'hello<div ui-view></div>'
            }).state('leagueState.teams',{
                url:'/teams',
                template :'<div>team in leagues, i will not populate in ui-view of index.html</div>'
            })
            .state('fixturesState',{
                url:'/fixtures',
                template :'<div>fixtures</div>'
            })
            .state('teamState',{
                url:'/team',
                template :'<div>teams</div>'
            });`

Comment: Three non nested states 
1.leagueState
2.fixtureState
3.TeamState

leagueState has child state, so league state shud have ui-view, cant i just populate in ui-view put in index.html using no names views?

Comment: I don't believe that's possible.

Comment: hmmn. so can i do like this?  when user will go to /leagues/state, can i wipeout the template which is in index.html ui-view (of leagueState), as of now i am getting both templates, one of parent leagueState that gets into ui-view @index.html and 2nd of leagueState.teams in ui-view given to parent template. when i hit leagues/state